# Transaction log File Backup

Tags: sql-server-2008, transaction-log

I am using Sql server 2008 with full recovery model , My Transaction log file size is (172 M), i tried to backup the log file, the backup process completed successfully, but its only took (1000 KB)

Comment: This is more a question for Server Fault (http://serverfault.com/).  Regardless, you should expand upon what you mean by "it only took (1000KB)" and what you expected instead.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the transaction log backup will be related to the amount of activity in the database, not the size of the log file; remember you will need a full backup of the database, and all transaction log backups in sequence in order to do point-in-time recovery.